# What and where is the Cordova Webview?

Tags: cordova, webview

I'm trying to understand what is the webview used in Cordova. I was thinking that it was a webview fully implemented, with code to render html, deal with javascript, etc.

But when i package for Android, for example, i only see about 140kb in classes.dex

So, seems that the webview for Android, for example, is just something that calls a Google's Chrome container? And the same for all other platforms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone can correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe Cordova uses the default webview on the device. This would explain why the package is so small. Cordova provides the interface so that you can just go ahead and develop your HTML5 app and let it take care of communicating with the webview for you.

Now, there's a separate project that works with Cordova call Crosswalk (https://crosswalk-project.org/) that embeds a Chrome webview into the project so that all devices will have the exact same webview to ensure support for certain features and a consistent experience. The apk for projects that use Crosswalk can be around 30 - 40mb more because of this. The webview is definitely different on different platforms (for example, on Windows Phone it is a version of IE / Edge), which is why a consistent webview is helpful. I personally have run into issues because of differences in the webview when developing on Windows Phone vs. Android.

Comment: Thanks, the crosswalk is what i was searching for!